# How can I generate example versions that match a PEP 440 Version specifier in Python?

Tags: python, regex, version, packaging, pep

I have a PEP 440 Version specifier, such as `">=1.0,<2.0"`, that defines a range of valid versions for a Python package. I would like to generate a list of example versions that match this specifier.

For example, if the specifier is `">=1.0,<2.0"`, some valid example versions could be `1.0.1`, `1.5.3`, or `1.9.9`. Invalid example versions could be `0.9.5`, `2.0.0`, or `3.0.0`.

What is the easiest way to generate such example versions in Python (3.10)? Should I use a regular expression, the packaging library, or some other method?

My current approach is to `split` at commas and remove the [comparison operators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) from the version specifier and then `try` to create a `Version` from it.

In the following example I allow invalid versions, because I don't mind them for my use case.

```py
from packaging.version import Version, InvalidVersion

comp_ops = ["===", "~=", "<=", ">=", "!=", "==", "<", ">"]    # order matters
version_spec = ">=1.0,<2.0"
versions = []

for v in version_spec.split(','):
    version = v
    for op in comp_ops:
        version = version.removeprefix(op)
    try:
        versions.append(Version(version))
    except InvalidVersion:
        pass
```

Comment: the question is how to convert a string of boolean conditions to a numeric range?

Comment: I guess yes, one could phrase it like that. Or rather "convert a string of boolean conditions to a numeric range and sample from the range".

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I tried is just repeatedly generating random strings of the form `r"[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]"` and parsing versions from it until I get `n_samples` many valid versions.

```py
import random
from packaging.version import parse, Version
from packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet

def version_samples(specifier: SpecifierSet, n_versions:int=3) -> list[Version]:
    sample_versions = []
    while len(sample_versions) < n_versions:
        version = ".".join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(3))
        parsed_version = parse(version)
        if specifier.contains(parsed_version):
                sample_versions.append(version)
    return sample_versions

specifier = SpecifierSet(">=1.0,<2.0")
print(version_samples(specifier))        # sample output: ['1.9.9', '1.0.4', '1.8.3']
```

I guess this approach can be extended for more general [PEP 440 public version identifiers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#public-version-identifiers) (`[N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]`).
The downside of this approach is that it's guess and check and doesn't (purposely) consider edge cases.